# How can you create an auto playlist with the HTML5 Audio tag?

Tags: html, html5-audio, playlist

How can you create an auto playlist with the audio tag from HTML5?

What I'm trying to achieve is a player with only the play/pause button big 30x25 px, the player autoplays when the page loads and when the song ends it'll play the next song automatically. Trying to have 3-4 songs in a playlist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this post: [using jquery + <audio> w/ php/mysql to loop playback times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517726/using-jquery-audio-w-php-mysql-to-loop-playback-times/9527327#9527327)

```
var sfx = new Audio('sfx.wav');
var sounds = a.addTextTrack('metadata');

// add sounds we care about
sounds.addCue(new TextTrackCue('dog bark', 12.783, 13.612, '', '', '', true));
sounds.addCue(new TextTrackCue('kitten mew', 13.612, 15.091, '', '', '', true));

function playSound(id) {
  sfx.currentTime = sounds.getCueById(id).startTime;
  sfx.play();
}
```

I just updated this with a better example of using cues as specified here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html

Comment: ...How does that help me with what I'm trying to get?

Comment: I'm not trying to have a sfx playing when you press a link or something. I'm trying to get an mp3/wav/ogg to autoplay once the webpage is loaded, that player to have a pause/play button and once the first song is done to autoplay the second one and so on.

Comment: + no jQuery included, just JS

Comment: Your questions says "How can you create an auto playlist with the audio tag from HTML5?".  If you used the code I provided and called `playSound(yourtrackid)` on page load, voila!

Comment: "What I'm trying to achieve is a player with only the play/pause button big 30x25 px, the player autoplays when the page loads and when the song ends it'll play the next song automatically. Trying to have 3-4 songs in a playlist." And that is what I'm trying to archive.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using similar code to the following on my site to play a continuous playlist of audio on my site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var nextVideo = "/Link/To/Next/File.mp3";
        var audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audio_with_controls');
        audioPlayer.addEventListener('ended', PlayNext);

        function PlayNext() {
            audioPlayer.src = nextVideo;
            audioPlayer.play();
        }
</script>
```

It would be very easy for you to add an array of files that you could loop through (using arrays etc).
You could also have the playlist displayed to the user, with each track being a clickable link that would call JS to change the player's "src" property.

Hope this helps!