# HTML5 Audio Streaming should display title

Tags: html, audio, streaming

I am using HTML5 audio control for streaming.

Is it possible that the title is displayed? (Winamp can do this)

Comment: Here one solution of the same question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636449/how-can-you-create-an-auto-playlist-with-the-html5-audio-tag

Comment: I think this is actually quite a good question, and one that seems to have been ignored a little bit by the spec. However, you'll probably be able to use a library like https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader to get the metadata you need - as seen here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370222/how-to-get-audio-tag-infomation. Not quite sure how this will work when streaming, however.

Comment: The title exists in the ID3 metadata of MP3 (not all have it, depends on MP3 maker). Use Javascript to read the bytes. If you start something (eg: code to read at least 1st, 2nd, 3rd byte values, I'll help you finish)